# JavaFX: NullPointerException in a Runnable

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception

We are creating a Dominion card game.

The game uses MVC, Client-Server, and Java Serialization for communication.

The code fragment posted below shows the client-side class for reading messages from the server:

```
public class ReadMsgFromServer implements Runnable {
    ObjectInputStream in;
    ServiceLocatorClient sl = ServiceLocatorClient.getServiceLocator();
    ChatMessageLobby msg;
    Client_Model model;
    Client_View_playingStage view_playingStage;

    public ReadMsgFromServer (ObjectInputStream in, Client_Model model){
        this.in = in;   
        this.model=model;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        GameObject obj;

        try {
            while ((obj = (GameObject) this.in.readObject()) !=null){

                switch (obj.getType()) {

                case ChatMessageLobby:
                    ChatMessageLobby msg = (ChatMessageLobby) obj;                   
                    String name = msg.getName();
                    String text = msg.getMsg();
                    sl.getTextAreaLobby().appendText(name+": "+text+"\n");
                    sl.getTextAreaLobby().selectPositionCaret(sl.getTextAreaLobby().getText().length());    
                    break;

                case InformationObject:
                    break;

                case GameParty:
                    GameParty newGame = (GameParty) obj;

                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                           @Override 
                           public void run() {
                            sl.addNewGame(newGame);
                           }
                       });
                    break;

                //updating the ListView of this client when he logs in (he needs to see all open games when he enters the lobby)    
                case UpdateLobby:

                    UpdateLobby toUpdate = (UpdateLobby) obj;

                    Iterator<GameParty> iter = toUpdate.getListOfOpenGames().iterator();
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                               @Override 
                               public void run() {

                                   while (iter.hasNext()){
                                       sl.addNewGame(iter.next());
                                   }
                               }
                           });
                    break;

                case UpdateGameParty:

                    UpdateGameParty newUpdate = (UpdateGameParty) obj;

                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                           @Override 
                           public void run() {
                               sl.updateGameParty(newUpdate.getGameParty());

                           }
                       });
                    break;

                case JoinGameParty:
                    JoinGameParty join=(JoinGameParty) obj;
                    GameParty gamePartyToJoin=join.getSelectedGameParty();

                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override 
                           public void run() {
                               Stage playingStage = new Stage();            
                               playingStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                               view_playingStage = new Client_View_playingStage (playingStage, model,false);
                               new Client_Controller_playingStage(model, view_playingStage,gamePartyToJoin); 
                               view_playingStage.start();
                        }
                       });


                    break;

                case CancelGame:
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override 
                           public void run() {
                                view_playingStage.stop();
                           }
                       });

                default:
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Each client can create a new game in the lobby. Other clients can join this game.

If a client joins a game, on client-side he will read the `GameObject` type `JoinGameParty` (`switch` case number 6).

There, his view `playingStage` will be created on the JavaFX Thread in a new `Runnable`.

For this view, I've made the instance variable `"Client_View_playingStage view_playingStage;"` which will be initialized in the mentioned `switch` case. The view starts without problems.

Now I want implement the following function:

- Until a game is not full, the host can end the game at any time.
- If he does this, his view and all views of the other clients will be closed and they will get back to the lobby.
- To stop the view, respectively, the stage (`stage.hide();` in abstract class), I've implemented the `switch` case number 7 (`CancelGame`).
- I want to use the instance variable `view_playingStage` which should have been initialized already in the `switch` case number 6 (`JoinGameParty`).
- But on the line `view_playingStage.stop();`, within the `run` method, it will cause a `NullPointerException` on JavaFX Thread.

**Why is this happening?** I have initialized the instance variable `view_playingStage`. **Or am I forced to work here with properties (`ObjectProperty`, etc.)?**

Comment: Does the `NullPointerException` occurs because `view_playingStage` is `null` or something within `run()` method is `null`?

Comment: Exception is thrown on the line where I call the stop method of the stage, so view_playingStage is null

Comment: problem is solved

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them